# No me genera la tabla con spring boot y mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

Estoy creando un pequeño programa con Spring boot usando MySQL.
Al momento de crear la tabla con la anotación @Table, en la BD no se crea ningún registro. La conexión si la hace pero la creación de la tabla no. Me podrían ayudar?

Este es mi registro de BD

[image: Este es la carga de mi BD]
[image: Este esmi model]
[image: Este es la salida de mi log])

Comment: Hola! Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Código y errores como texto, nadie va a replicar cosas desde imágenes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: En el application.properties puedes quitar el spring.jpa.database-platform=... y así spring-boot automáticamente seleccionara el dialecto, eso por lo menos debería eliminar un warning que tienes.